# Calling an Angular service in d3.queue - defer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using a d3.queue() object successfully to retrieve json from an api endpoint:

```
d3.queue().defer(d3.json, "http://myurl.com/myendpoint")
```

(I'm using Angular) but I'd like to instead call my Angular service that calls that endpoint.

(Endpoint code:)

```
getSAData: function(myUrl){
    return $http.get(fullUrl)
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error retrieving data');
        })
}
```

I don't see any examples of doing this, but my attempt:

```
d3.queue().defer(ApiService.getMyData("http://myurl.com/myendpoint"))
```

is throwing the error:

```
Uncaught Error
at Vt.defer (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:6:28622)
```

Answer (score 0):

After I posted it I saw where the actual syntax for calling functions is (functionName, [parameters,]), so:

```
d3.queue().defer(ApiService.getMyData, "http://myurl.com/myendpoint")
```

is the syntax.